# Wordpress print_thumbnail not giving correct url

Tags: php, apache, wordpress

I've been having a hard time with this issue.
I'm running Wordpress 3.3.1 on Ubuntu Server 64bit

So I'm able to upload an image and view it using the url provided.
However, when I set it as a feature image it appears that the function
print_thumbnail is not giving me the correct address.
It's adding in /var/www/ before my /wp-content/uploads/etc...
So the absolute path name would be correct on my machine with the help of some symlinks.

I tried changing the css on the file to remove the /var/www/ and verified that this did indeed find my image and worked. I've been seeing a lot of posts that tell me change chmod 777 and back to 755 as in [wp print_thumbnail function is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851075/wp-print-thumbnail-function-is-not-working) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003277/wp-print-thumbnail-function-not-working-correctly I don't know how this was suppose to fix the issue since this seems to be a pathing problem. Is there some sort of redirection based on permissions? Anyways, it didn't work.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is an example post
http://mobile.cs.fsu.edu/google-chrome-app-on-android-market/

Answer (score 0):

You might try this instead of `print_thumbnail`.

```
<?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail(); // Outputs <img/> object with src="thumbnail-href"
}
```

Similarly, this would also work:

```
<?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    echo( get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID() ) );
}
```

If you've setup multiple featured image sizes in your functions.php....

```
<?php
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 120, 120 );
add_image_size( 'subfeature', 940, 300 );
```

you could reference a size in this manner (where `subfeature` is the name of the size):

```
<?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    echo( get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'subfeature' ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the function I found out that it uses get_bloginfo function to print out stylesheet directory

```
$output = '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/timthumb.php?src='.$thumbnail.'&amp;h='. $height .'&amp;w='. $width .'&amp;zc=1"';
```

In the [wordpress codex of get_bloginfo](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo), it says:

> 'stylesheet_directory' - Returns the stylesheet directory URL of the
>   active theme. (Was a local path in earlier WordPress versions.)
>   Consider using [get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) instead.

Change the get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') to get_stylesheet_directory_uri()

I did not try it myself, hope it helps.