# print_thumbnail is Not behaving well in wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

```
print_thumbnail(
 $arr[$i]["thumb_small"], $arr[$i]["use_timthumb"], 
 $arr[$i]["fulltitle"] ,$width_small,$height_small
);
```

It returns in image tag

```
src="/domains/web2760/web//wp-content/uploads/2012/01/Gates-124086_132x58.jpg"
```

instead of

```
src="/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/Gates-124086_132x58.jpg"
```

Please help me in this

Comment: check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408851/wordpress-print-thumbnail-not-giving-correct-url

Answer (score 1):

Don't use print_thumbnail, this is an internal WP function, you must use get_the_post_thumbnail:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail

or if you are in the loop, you can use the_post_thumbnail:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail

Comment: Thanks for sharing this because some plugins still reference the latter, when we should be using the former.  I went in and made the modification which is now helping my wordpress project out.